# Elements which don't have a $\gcd$ in $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-5}]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> Show that in the ring $R = \{a + b\sqrt{-5} |\, a,b\,\, \in \,\mathbb{Z} \}$
>   the elements $\alpha = 3$ and $\beta = 1 + 2\sqrt{-5}$  are relatively prime but $\alpha\gamma$ and $\beta\gamma$ have no $\gcd$ in $R$, where $\gamma = 7(1+2\sqrt{-5})$.

I've tried using the fact if $x$ and $y$ are relatively prime than there exists $p$ and $q$ such that
$xp+yq = 1$ and  then we got inconsistent equation like $3$ divides $3^n +1$. 
Also for g.c.d. 
as $y \in R$, $\alpha\gamma$ and $\beta\gamma$ have g.c.d as $y \in R$?

So clueless for both parts. Tried hard.
Please help!

Comment: Since you're new, I'd like to give you some advice about the site: **To get the best possible answers, you should explain what your thoughts on the problem are**. That way, people won't tell you stuff you already know, and they can write answers at an appropriate level; also, people tend to be more willing to help if you show that you've tried the problem yourself. Lastly, some may consider your post rude because it is phrased as a command, not a request for help, so please consider rewriting it.

Comment: So you tried to use the Bachet-Bézout identity, unfortunately this idea cannot work as your domain is not Bézout. Maybe there is something else to try with the norms of those elements...

Answer (score 1):

I tried solving it and could solve the first part of the problem, i.e. $\alpha = 3$ and $\beta = 1 + 2\sqrt{-5}$ are relatively prime.

Lets take   $3=(a+\sqrt{-5})(c+\sqrt{-5}d)$ then we have $\overline 3 =(a-\sqrt{-5})(c-\sqrt{-5}d)$

Multiplying these two we get $9=(a^2+5b^2)(c^2+5d^2)$. Using this we can show that 3 is irreducible element and only possible divisors of 3 in in the given Ring are 1 and 3.

Now as 3 does not divide $1 + 2\sqrt{-5}$, we get $\alpha = 3$ and $\beta = 1 + 2\sqrt{-5}$ are relatively prime.

Comment: your solution is very good. Please also help for the second part of the question.

Comment: showing 3 is irreducible doesn't automatically mean the only possible divisors of 3 are 1 and 3. It just means that if 3 = ab then either a or b must be a unit.

Comment: for the 2nd part : $\alpha\gamma = 3.7.(1+2\sqrt{-5})$ and  $\beta\gamma = (1+2\sqrt{-5}).7.(1+2\sqrt{-5})$ which implies potential candidates for gcd are 1,-1( units in $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-5}]$, 7, $1+2\sqrt{-5}$. Now using the definition of gcd all 4 candidates can be rejected

Comment: @Sarkat Isn't $7(1+2√-5)$ also a potential candidate for gcd here?

Answer (score 0):

[More of a get-you-started than an answer] You have written that if $x$ and $y$ are relatively prime then there exist $p$ and $q$ such that $xp+yq=1$. What you have left out is that $p$ and $q$ are in $R$. That means $p=a+b\sqrt{-5}$ and $q=c+d\sqrt{-5}$ for some integers $a,b,c,d$. So you're trying to show you can't have $$3(a+b\sqrt{-5})+(1+2\sqrt{-5})(c+d\sqrt{-5})=1$$ Multiply everything out, you'll get an equation for the real parts and an equation for the imaginary parts. See if you can show there's no solution --- EDIT --- I mean, see if you can find a solution.

Comment: I think what you are trying to say is that we'll have to show that a solution exists for the equation : $$3(a+b\sqrt{-5})+(1+2\sqrt{-5})(c+d\sqrt{-5})=1$$ .I tried doing that but got inconsistent equations.

Comment: I'm sorry, yes, that's what I meant. I'll edit.

Comment: On equating the real and imaginary parts I got $$3a + c - 10d = 1$$ and $$3b + 2c + d = 0$$ These equations come out to be inconsistent.

Comment: OK, so what's happening here is that "relatively prime" doesn't mean $xp+yq=1$, it means there's no $\delta$ in $R$ that divides both $\alpha$ and $\beta$. In the integers, those amount to the same thing, but not in $R$. So what you really want to show first is that there's no $\delta$ in $R$ that divides both $\alpha$ and $\beta$. Then you get to work on showing that even though $\alpha\gamma$ and $\beta\gamma$ have common divisors, they have no gcd --- no common divisor divisible by every common divisor. Sorry that I steered you in the wrong direction earlier.